# Color autocorrected on my Canon G10 in the middle of filming, any tips for editing in post?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, color-correction, canon

I was filming a music recital when the color autocorrected on my canon g10. I am new at all of this, but I recently bought final cut pro x and I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction for correcting this. There is a 5 second period in the video where the colors shift from dark to light, how would I go about smoothing this out in post?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily.  You would need to apply a color correction to try to replicate the change.  If you can use the color correction to get the beginning and end pretty close, you can then use keyframes to have it blend between them and hopefully overcome the adjustment, but results are still probably going to be so-so and it isn't trivial to get even a mediocre fix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured this wouldn't happen without some sort of keyframe kind of thing. I guess in the future if I have it set to auto, I will make sure it is completely adjusted to the room (it's too bad, it must have been when the hall lights dimmed or something)

Comment: @AustinSlominski - yeah, in general with video you want to try to avoid things like auto-exposure and auto-white balance.  I've seen them ruin far too many shots.